# toggle between user filters?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Say I have two groups: `Group 1` & `Group 2`

Group 1 needs access to a value in the [Business Unit] dimension, lets say "Degree" [Business Unit], while Group 2 needs access to just one value in [department] dimension, lets say "Human Resources" [Department].

I can't have two user filter sets in my filter pane because it'll conflict and just give me a blank view of my data. Is there a way I can toggle between them based on which group is trying to access the dashboard?

`if ISMEMBEROF('Group 1') then [User Filter Option (Business Unit])`

`else [User Filter Option (Department)] end`

didn't end up working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some documents on how to set up RLS - Row Level Security on multiple dimensions

[image]
Fast overview:
https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/publish_userfilters.htm

More details with examples:
https://tableauandbehold.com/2020/12/09/quick-explanation-of-row-level-security-in-tableau/

Underlying Theory:
https://www.tableau.com/learn/whitepapers/row-level-security-entitlements-tables

Wade